# Whats is the best way to make image transparent?

Tags: html, css

I need to add a transparent image to a page and here are two ways - save is as semi transparent png (it will have some transparent parts anyway) or save it at full fill and then add 'opacity' in css. What is the proper way and why?

Comment: Depends on your purposes. There is no "best" way. Voted to close as subjective. If the image has only *some* transparent parts, this cannot be achieved with CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549768/which-is-superior-css-transparency-or-png-transparency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the image as a transparent png. Not all browsers support the `opacity` style.

Comment: Not all browsers support PNG, that doesn't mean you should avoid it. A PNG can be *orders of magnitude* larger than a jpeg. If it's acceptable for the `opacity` to be ignored and degrade gracefully to full opacity, then a jpeg might still be the better option.